# Как изменить background-image при клике на маленькое изображение

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Добрый вечер. Необходимо когда кликаешь на маленькое изображение менялся фон страницы. Я чайник в этом деле пытался сделать сам не получилось подскажите пожалуйста.
Вообще есть 6-изображений одинаковых размеров просто когда на них кликаешь менялся фон на нужный мне.
Заранее всем спасибо

Comment: Циклически менять 6 картинок по клику?

Comment: Разметка нужна .

Comment: Кликнул поменялся фон .Пока не кликнешь на другое изображение тогда поменяется на другой фон
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  (function() {
    var images = [
      'https://yt3.ggpht.com/-A58yPmvdnIc/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/2o1tCSQHEG0/s100-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg',
      'https://yt3.ggpht.com/-DBNBnMLsnrs/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/onFqjfb9JQs/s100-mo-c-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no/photo.jpg',
      'http://puppo.ru/media/icons/10/simpsons_gone_fishing.jpg',
      'https://fanparty.ru/fanclubs/the-simpsons/gallery/1568512_the_simpsons_medium.jpg',
      'http://gumplay.com/img/games/5639b985ae3d8.jpg',
      'http://lizasimpson.com/uploads/_pages/613/simpsons-avatars-2.gif'
    ];
    var idx = -1;
    $('.img').click(function() {
      idx++;
      if (idx >= images.length)
        idx = 0;
      $(this).css({"background-image": "url(" + images[idx] + ")"});
    }).click();
  })();
});
```

```css
.img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img">&nbsp;</div>
```